# IPAD APP Design Question - Lots of pages, with little to do

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am new to IPhone/iPad development and have a application design question.

1) I have about 60 different pages I converting from a Flash file.  They are largely pretty devoid of stuff to do.  Mainly reading and and some images.

2) There are a few interactive things (buttons, animations,etc.) on on about 50% of the pages

My initial thinking is to use a navigation controller (hidden, as I don't want as part of my design) to use the push and pop functionality.  Each page would have it's own viewcontroller.

My other thought was to use hidden UINavigationController, but to group pages in specific areas and have multiple NIB files read from one view controller.

Is one better that the other? Or have more advantages than the other?  Or is there a better way?

Comment: "Mainly reading and and some images."  -- and ... and ...?

Comment: can it be placed into one pdf with document-level navigation?

Comment: Eimantas - It is more tree like.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to answer this, but you could probably have a few NIBs and ViewControllers and reuse them.  There are a million ways to do simple navigation without UINavigationController -- it might be more of a pain that not using it.

For example, is navigation always like a tree (forward, forward, forward, back, back, back) --- or could it be more free form around a graph?

If navigation is simply push and pop, then use it, but try to keep the number of different viewcontrollers/NIBs to a minimum (for maintenance purposes)

Comment: Actually, it is very much tree like, but it will have a breadcrumb to jump back a few levels.  But the design is very hierarchal.  Also, can you give me an example of showing new views without navigation controller?

Answer (score 0):

The usual recommendation is one view controller per full page of content.  However, if your content is remarkably similar, reusing the view controller is valid.  Before proceeding, I'd think carefully about your navigation model:

1. Will users be able to jump from any page to another (say like a magazine)?
2. Do some pages require the user to visit other pages first?

For (2), the push/pop model works quite well, whereas for (1) the push/pop model of a UINavigationController may be too much trouble.

So focus on your presentation, and then let the code follow from that.

Comment: It is like #2 up above and is tree like but with a breadcrumb and possibility of jumping up a few levels.